# Resolving an image uri relative to application root

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, relative-path

I am using Asp.Net MVC 5.  Assume for this question that my application is being served from `localhost:9000/app`.

I've got this in my `_layout.cshtml`:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/logo.png")" />
```

When the user requests `localhost:9000/app/foobar`, the image URI is correctly resolved to `localhost:9000/app/Content/logo.png`.

But when the user requests `localhost:9000/app/folder/bender_is_great`, the image URI resolves to `localhost:9000/app/folder/Content/logo.png`.

How do I get the image URI to always resolve relative to the application root, not relative to the requested path?

Edit:  `Server.MapPath("~/Content/logo.png")` has the same issue.  It's resolving relative to the requested path, not the application root.

Comment: This should work fine ! Do you have any custom route configs ?

Comment: No, just the basic HomeController route config that comes with MVC projects.  Turns out it was my URL rewrite rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was my URL rewrite rules for friendly HTML5 URLs without the hashbang (#!).  The rewriting engine set an item on the application: `"IIS_WasUrlRewritten"`.  [`Url.Content(...)` calls into `UrlUtil`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/749384689e027a2fcd29eb79a9137b94cea611a8/src/System.Web.WebPages/Utils/UrlUtil.cs#L95), which pays attention to this item and changes its behavior.  This [Microsoft Support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2905164) says:

> To resolve the tilde notation to the rewritten URLs by using the same behavior as in Web Pages Razor V2, set the IIS_WasUrlRewritten context to false in each Web page or in Application_BeginRequest in Global.asax for the global setting as follows:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Context.Items["IIS_WasUrlRewritten"] = false;
}
```

> Note The change of the IIS_WasUrlRewritten context affects the tilde notation not only in the HTML elements, but also in the MVC helper methods. For example, if it is set to false, the tilde notation in Url.Content and Html.ActionLink returns the rewritten URLs.

So far this code hasn't caused any problems in my application and has resolved the issue.