# ActionLink and relative path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I can't find out how to solve this. I have two URLs. These are `/my-url-1` and `/my-url-2`. Both going to different views.

The thing is that I have an ActionLink on `/my-url-1`'s view which should make `/my-url-2` and go to that view.

The problem is that ActionLink makes `/my-url-1/my-url-2` as the URL and not just `/my-url-2`.

I was searching two days about how to fix it but couldn't find anything.

PD: I'm not using Areas so please don't tell me that I just should put the "area" parameter as a "".

These are two urls which goes to different controllers and different actions.

View which has the ActionLink (URL:`/my-url-1`) :

```
<div class="btn-index-container">
     @Html.ActionLink("Url 2", "MyAction", "MyController")
</div>
```

This ActionLink should render:

```
<a href="/my-url-2">Url 2</a>
```

But it's rendering:

```
<a href="/my-url-1/my-url-2">Url 2</a>
```

where `/my-url-1` is my current URL

**Route Config**

```
         routes.MapRoute(
            name: "route1",
            url: "my-url-2", //without parameters
            defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction" },
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "route2",
            url: "my-url-1", //without parameters too
            defaults: new { controller = "MyController2", action = "MyAction2" }
        );
```

So, when I go to `localhost:port/my-url-1` it loads `MyAction2` which renders a view. This view has inside an `ActionLink`(described above) which should render a `/my-url-2` link.

Comment: @Leandrohereñu Since you have not provided any code or detailed explanation of what you are trying to achieve. If you are trying to navigate from one view to other by placing it as a link. You can use

 <a href="@Url.Action("VIEW-NAME","CONTROLLER")">LINK-TEXT</a>

Comment: It should be `@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "Action", "Controller")`, the controller and action are in the wrong order in your example

Comment: It isn't that some of us *want* some code, it's that we *cannot help you* without seeing your code.  Imagine going to your auto mechanic and not letting him actually inspect your car.

Comment: @Haldo you are right! I wrote here in the bad order. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @Tango! How are you? I've tried with ActionLink, Url.Action and RouteLink but all take the same problem. Thanks for answer!

Comment: Sorry @Amy. I thought that the code was no necessary. I thought that it wasn't to difficult to get in mind what was going on. Do you have some advice for it?

Comment: I'm guessing its because of how your `MyAction` method is configured.  Can you show us how routing for that method is configured?

Comment: yes of course! I'll add it into the question

Comment: Something doesn't seem right regarding your routing, but I can't put my finger on it.  You might consider using something like https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/ to get a handle on what is happening under the covers.

Comment: @Amy  I found a post which was written for you, here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665297/resolving-an-image-uri-relative-to-application-root

please, as I can't comment on that post because my reputation, could you update the link for get the MVC code? The new URL is: 
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/

Comment: @Leandrohereñu That *looks* like a different issue.  Does the solution there fix your problem?  If so, props for finding it.

Comment: @Leandrohereñu Thank you, I have updated the link and my answer in general.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've worked inside the MVC framework and I could told you about how `Url.RouteUrl` or `Html.RouteLink` works. At the end, the method which create the URL is `GetVirtualPathForArea` (this method is called before `UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrl`, which receive the `VirtualPathData.cs` created by `GetVirtualPathForArea`, as a parameter) from `System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.cs`.

Here I left a link to the MVC source code:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc

I found that, my `Request.ApplicationPath` was changing when I loaded `/my-url-1`. It was crazy because the application path was `/`.

At last, the problem was that the `/my-url-1` was pointing to a virtual directory created on the IIS some time ago by error.
To know where your IIS configuration file is, please follow the link below:

[remove virtual directory in IIS Express created in error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596366/remove-virtual-directory-in-iis-express-created-in-error)

The solution was remove the `.vs` directory (which contains the config `.vs\config\applicationhost.config`) and rebuild

I think most of the Helpers that render URLs works more or less in the same way, so I hope it'll useful for all of you!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, maybe no its necesary, just pass the parameters with null values, E.G.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Español", null, null, new { Lng = "es" }, null)
```

In this way, the parameters change, and the view is relative, depending on where you are.